# When I say float right, my image goes too far right, and a scrollbar appears

Tags: html, css, css-float

When I say float: right; my image goes too far right and a horizontal scrolling bar appears. How do I make it so that the image just goes to the edge of the page? This is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOU4Z.png This is what I want it to look like:https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlVxo.png.
The css code that I used is:

```
.main-img { 
width: 273px; 
float: right; 
}
```

The HTML code that I used is:

```
<div class="main-section">
    <div class="right-column-main">
        <div class="main-img">
            <img src="../Final/images/Pictureofwebsite.JPG" alt="Website Image">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left-column-main">
        <div class="heading-one">
            <h1>CodePen is a <strong>social development environment</strong> for front-end designers and developers.</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="heading-two">
            <h2>It's the best place to build and deploy a website, show off you work, build test cases, and find inspiration.</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="center-btn-group">
            <button class="sign-up">Sign Up for Free</button>
            <button class="learn-more">Learn More</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There is not enough information here for us to help you debug the problem. Please update your question using the "edit" link underneath it and include the relevant code a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can see the problem and be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, you just need to use flexbox.It is helpful.Do something like `body{display:flex;}` and then put img as last.

Feel free to ask more.I admit, the explanation on top was really blury.

Comment: How do I put the image as last?

Comment: Put the image as last thing in div that is like body styled, above

Comment: It still does the same thing as before. It did go over to the right but it overlaps the edge alot.